# Why "cannot move out of `new_state`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure"?

Tags: rust

i have a function:

```
if matches!(active_hot_key, HotKey::Cancel) {
                    let new_state = InputFsmHelpers::handle_hotkey_key_down(
                        command_system,
                        state,
                        active_hot_key,
                    )?;

                    return Ok((
                               None,
                               Box::new(|_post_command_state| new_state),
                               None,
                             ));
                }
```

`new_state` is of type `Option<Box<dyn InputFsmState>`.

tuple returned in `return Ok(...)` returns closure of type `Box<dyn Fn(&State) -> Option<Box<dyn InputFsmState>>>`;

I get this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `new_state`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
   --> src\app\input_system\states\block.rs:111:69
    |
105 |                     let new_state = InputFsmHelpers::handle_hotkey_key_down(
    |                         --------- captured outer variable
...
111 |                     return Ok((None, Box::new(|_post_command_state| new_state), None));
    |                                               ----------------------^^^^^^^^^
    |                                               |                     |
    |                                               |                     move occurs because `new_state` has type `std::option::Option<Box<dyn InputFsmState>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |                                               captured by this `Fn` closure
    |
help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content
    |
111 |                     return Ok((None, Box::new(|_post_command_state| new_state.as_ref()), None));
    |                                                                              +++++++++
```

I don't use `new_state` anywhere after the closure and I don't understand why this doesn't work?

I'd like to have it like this with `Fn` (so, without a `move`) and not go with `FnOnce`.
I guess i don't understand why error says that move happens at all?

Comment: Have you tried making the closure `move||`?

Comment: as i said, i don't want to go with `move/FnOnce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to have it like this with `Fn` (so, without a move) and not go with `FnOnce`. I guess i don't understand why error says that move happens at all?

Because the closure returns `new_state` by value, and it's not a `Copy` type. So it has to be moved out of the closure.

If it's moved out of the closure on the first call, then the second call can not work (there's nothing to move out), however `Fn` means the function must be callable multiple times. So there is an incompatiblity between the type of the function and its closure.

It might be clearer if you desugar: a closure is in essence a `struct` storing the "closed-over" items, and a function, so what you're asking for is:

```rust
struct Closure<T>(T);
impl Closure<T> {
    // Fn ~ &self
    // FnMut ~ &mut self
    // FnOnce ~ self
    fn call(&self) -> T {
        self.0
    }
}
```

Can you see how that doesn't work? You can't *move* the content out of the struct if you don't replace it or consume the entire structure.

Comment: does that mean i should return it by reference? like `&new_state`? would that be a solution?

Comment: @deezg I believe the pattern here is probably to move the construction of `state` into the closure. I.e. make a new `state` every time the closure is called.

Comment: @isaactfa not that i have some special reason, but i intentionally stored it into a variable so i don't have that function call each time closure is being called. in other words, so that closure struct captures only a variable. its not the case here, but just for the sake of the argument, lets say that creation of state is expensive - would then returning `&new_state` (a reference) from the closure be a solution?

Comment: @deezg No. `new_state` is owned by the function. When you return from the function `new_state` gets dropped and all references to it will be invalid, so your closure can't return a reference to it. In fact, I think the closure approach is exactly there to prevent unnecessarily creating expensive data structures. By making `new_state` inside of the closure, it only gets created when the caller needs it. The way you're doing it, it's always being created regardless of if the caller will actually end up using it.

Comment: @isaactfa i am either missing what you are saying or i am missing something fundamental about closures. my understanding is that `new_state` cannot be dropped when function ends specifically because closure captured its value. otherwise, how would any closure capture any variable ever? my understanding is that thats the whole point of closure: to capture variables from the function. in this case, i need it to capture it by immutable borrow.

Comment: @deezg yes returning a reference would work, and is exactly what the compiler suggests. Although you might need to convert the closure to a `move ||`, as the compiler might mis-infer the closure ownership. `move` closures are orthogonal to the `Fn` traits, it just means all the captures are done by value, otherwise the compiler infers whether the free variables should be captured by value or reference depending on how they're used.

Comment: @Masklinn i guess what confused me was a suggestion of `.as_ref()` instead of just `&new_state`.

Comment: @Masklinn are you saying that `move||` closures could still be used with an `Fn` trait? if so, i guess i've never seen an example of that; it was always with `FnOnce`.

Comment: @deezg it probably suggests `as_ref` because an `Option<&T>` is generally more convenient than an `&Option<T>`. And yes a `move ||` closure can absolutely be an `Fn`, these are largely orthogonal concerns: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b11eb9b303fa8d712590a7b230bff998 it's *extremely* common because `move` closures are necessary to precisely specify the capture of each free variable: http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/04/24/rust-pattern-precise-closure-capture-clauses/

Comment: @Masklinn thanks a bunch for going a step further to clarify. really appreciate it!